# Use two lists of values as parameters in a method and generate objects as many as the length of the two lists C#

Tags: c#, wpf, methods

I have the following two functions:

```cs
        //-----------------------------------FUNCTION 4-----------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Call the specified procedure that will import file1 in SQL Server
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connectionString"> The connection string to SQL server instance</param>
        /// <param name="importedfilepath"> The path of the browsed file</param>
        public static void LoadLayout(string connectionString, string importedfilepath)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                using (var command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.CommandText = "createselectedtableinDB";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableName", importedfilepath);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                        MessageBox.Show("Selected file was loaded successfully");
                }
            }
        }

        //-----------------------------------FUNCTION 5-----------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Call the specified procedure that will import file2 in SQL Server
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connectionString"> The connection string to SQL server instance</param>
        /// <param name="importedfilepath"> The path of the browsed file</param>
        public static void LoadBusinessChecks(string connectionString, string importedfilepath)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                using (var command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.CommandText = "createselectedtableinDB";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableName", importedfilepath);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                        MessageBox.Show("Selected file was loaded successfully");
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see the two functions take two parameters (which vary):

- Parameter 1: connection string to SQL server
- Parameter 2: FilePath

With those 2 parameters I am ok so far. What I want is to further optimize those two functions and basically have 1 function instead of those two. To do so, I know that I need to somehow specify:

- Proceduce name:

```cs
command.CommandText = "createselectedtableinDB"; //can take different values
```

- Procedure parameters and values (2 equal length list)

```cs
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableName", importedfilepath); //more than 1 parameter so import a list here
```

As a result, my expected *new mutated function* would be like follows:

Note that the code below it's not correct but I am trying to replicate my intuition so you can understand what I am trying to do. The code below will help you to understand what I am trying to achieve on high level.

```cs
        public static void LoadFiles(string connectionString, string importedfilepath, string ProcedureName, list ParameterName, list ParameterValue)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                using (var command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.CommandText = ProcedureName;
                    
                    foreach (string parametername in ParameterName)
                    {
                        foreach (string parametervalue in ParameterValue) 
                    {
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parametername, parametervalue ); //Generate as many as the length of the two lists
                    }
                    }
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                        MessageBox.Show("Selected file was loaded successfully");
                }
            }
        }
```

When calling the method from a LoadButton1_Click

```cs
        private void LoadButton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {   
            ParameterNamelist = list ["@TableName", "@Username", "@Email"]
            ParameterValuelist = list [importedfilepath, "Nikos", "nikos@stackoverflow.com"]

            var connectionString = SQLServerConnectionDetails();
            LoadFiles(connectionString, FileNameTextBox.Text, "SelectUsernameProcedure", ParameterNamelist, ParameterValuelist);
        }
```

When calling the exact method from a LoadButton2_Click

```cs
        private void LoadButton2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {   
            ParameterNamelist = list ["@TableName", "@ProductName"]
            ParameterValuelist = list [importedfilepath, "Choco"]

            var connectionString = SQLServerConnectionDetails();
            LoadFiles(connectionString, FileNameTextBox.Text, "SelectProductProcedure", ParameterNamelist, ParameterValuelist);
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? Are you asking for someone to write the new method for you?

Comment: @itsme86 How to achieve the use of two lists as parameters in a method. And use foreach (on list elements) to generate as many "command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parametername, parametervalue ); as the length of the lists. Sorry if I am not clear but I am new in C# and I am trying to learn the functionalities using my knowledge from Python.

Comment: @itsme86 It would be very helpful to me to use the Expected result code I posted (which I know is not correct) and provide some explanation on how to make it work. It would boost my knowledge with C#

Comment: @RyanWilson yeah you are right. I was busy so I didn't get the time to check your answer, which is also a very good solution. Thanks again for your time and apologise my  absence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) instead:

```
public static bool LoadFiles(string connectionString, string ProcedureName, 
    IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
    using var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    sqlConnection.Open();
    
     using var command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
     command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     command.CommandText = ProcedureName;
                
     foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> parameter in parameters)
     {
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
     }

     return (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0);
}
```

and then

```
private void LoadButton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        ["@TableName"] = importedfilepath,
        ["@Username"] = "Nikos",
        ["@Email"] = "nikos@stackoverflow.com"
    };

    var connectionString = SQLServerConnectionDetails();
    
    bool commandExecuted = LoadFiles(connectionString,
        "SelectUsernameProcedure", parameters);

    if (commandExecuted)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Selected file was loaded successfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer vc 74. Can I ask something about your code. Do you use any nuget package because the code Visual Studio propose to change ```KeyValue``` to ```KeyValuePair```

Comment: @NikSp and Visual Studio is right, code updated (no extra nuget package required)

Comment: Oohh ok I was lucky on that. :) Thanks again. I will try your code and let you know about the result.

Comment: Hey vc 74, I would like to ask you something about the answer you provided. I noticed that the SQL connection does not close in the code attached. Can this cause a problem t to other features? Because for example the MessageBox.Show() is not shown in my screen. Could the open SQL connection affect whether or not the MessageBox is shown?

Comment: @NikSp The connection is disposed (`using` statement) which will close it. The result of the method is a boolean so there should not be any side effects. It is normal that you only get `false` because from MSDN: "For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.", in your case the result will always be -1. What result did you expect to get?

Comment: The result is fine and works successfully. I was wondering if the absence of connection closing statement was affecting the messagebox.show() window to get generated. As you imply since the result of the commend is -1 the messagebox will never be generated because the If statement is command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0. If I change the statement to command.ExecuteNonQuery() >=-1 the messagebox will be generated right?

Comment: vc 74 Indeed by changing the statement to command.ExecuteNonQuery() >=-1 the message box was generated :)

Comment: @NikSp But then do you need to return anything? The method could return void and throw an exception in case of SQL error.

Comment: VC 74 I will trust you on this. Which option is more effective in your opinion. I am new with C# and giving as output a message box to say that the procedure was executed with no error is sufficient to me. I am willing to hear also different thoughts :)

Comment: What's important is that the message box display is not embedded in `LoadFiles` (so that it can be reused in a different context) and that this method returns a significant response to the caller. Since errors can only be propagated via exceptions in this case, `void LoadFiles` does the job imho.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a `Dictionary<string, object>` into the method instead of two separate lists:

Example Dictionary:

```
 Dictionary<string, object> myparams = new Dictionary<string, object>()
 {
    {"@TableName", importedfilepath },
    {"@ProductName", "Choco" }
 };
```

New Method:

```
 public static void LoadFiles(string connectionString, string ProcedureName,
          Dictionary<string, object> @params)
 {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            using (var command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = ProcedureName;
                    
                foreach (string key in @params.Keys)
                {                            
                     command.Parameters.AddWithValue(key, @params[key]); 
                }
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                    MessageBox.Show("Selected file was loaded successfully");
            }
        }
 }
```

Since you state you want to use your pseudo code from above, with the two lists, then it would work as so, I would suggest using the `Dictionary` approach provided above, but to satisfy your question:

```
//This is not a very safe way
//1. Both lists would need to have the same Count
//2. Parameters names would need to be ordered the same as Parameter values
public static void LoadFiles(string connectionString, string ProcedureName, 
                                List<string> ParameterName, List<object> ParameterValue)
{
       if(ParameterName.Count != ParameterValue.Count) 
          throw new Exception("Lists are of different Count");

       using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
       {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            using (var command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
               command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               command.CommandText = ProcedureName;
                    
               for(int i = 0; i < ParameterName.Count; i++)
               {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(ParameterName[i], ParameterValue[i]); //Generate as many as the length of the two lists
               }
                           
                    
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                    MessageBox.Show("Selected file was loaded successfully");
            }
        }
}
```